# How to make dialog layout interact with Gridview in MainActivity class

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, dialog

I have a gridview that calls installed apps
I have a Dialog layout.xml that when clicking on an item in GridView the dialog is called
What I need to do is to call the method uninstall application with the button in the Dialog

I need to return an action to the gridview Example: deleting an item in gridview with a button in dialog layout

```js
            Dialog myDialog;
   ...
   myDialog=new Dialog(this);
   ...
   // long click
            grdView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
    
                        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_menu);
                        myDialog.show();
      
                    return true;
                    }
            });
   
   
   
   *Button1
   Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", strPackageName, null); 
   Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri); 
   startActivity(it); 
   
   *Button2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d96PT.png)

Comment: The question title should be in English.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make function for showing dialog like this

```
public void showDialog(){  

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_menu, null);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setView(dialogView);
    dialog.show();
 }
```

then call this function inside of you gridview item click.

```
 grdView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

                    showDialog();

                return true;
                }
        });
```